# Grails g:tags does not support the doller($) sign in regex for pattern ? why?

Tags: regex, grails

Grails `g:tags` does not support inline pattern validation with dollar ($) sign. You can validate the field with jQuery. But is there any solution for the inline `g:tag` support for dollar sign with grails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It supports `$` sign with escape character `\` so you need to use it like `\$`

Example of `<g:field ............. />`

```
<g:field name="abc" type="text" pattern=".*([.,/])\$" />
```